# How to make partitions after installing Ubuntu using "Erase everything on the drive and install Ubuntu" option

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a 750GB sata hard drive. I have installed Ubuntu using the option "Erase everything on the drive and install Ubuntu". Now the installation is completed and I have a big partition of almost 745Gb.

- size: 745 GB — 722 GB free (3.2% full)
- device: /dev/sda2
- partition type: Linux Filesystem
- Content: Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root

There's also a swap partition:

- size: 4.2 GB (4,220,518,400 bytes)
- device: /dev/sda3
- partition type: Linux Swap
- Content: Swap (version 1) — Active

I don't know whether Ubuntu is installed in it or not. I want from the remaining 722GB, 600GB to create two or three different partitions.

Can I make these new  partitions in such a way that in future if I want to install Windows for a dual-boot it will be possible to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699355/install-windows-10-alongside-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: You need to boot a live session, the same as when you installed it, open GParted and resize `/` . And you installed in BIOS/Legacy mode which means that you will need to recover the Grub bootloader after installing Windows. Generally better to install Windows first. Either OS has provisions in their installers for the users to create and install in different partitions. In Ubuntu such option appears in the same dialog where you decided to "Erase..."and it's called "Something else".

Comment: Since you did not mention sda1 and swap is sda3, not the BIOS typical sda5, I guess you have an UEFI install. If partitioning is gpt and sda1 is ESP - efi system partition (FAT32 format), then you must be sure to boot the Windows installer in UEFI boot mode. Windows only installs & boots  on gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. In UEFI mode Windows will not erase the grub boot loader, but will reorder UEFI boot menu to make Windows first in boot order.

Comment: Show me a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` of /dev/sda and I'll take a look. If you're going to dual-boot with Windows, it's preferred that you install Windows first, then Ubuntu... it saves a lot of pain later. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema
here is the screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ruww.png

Comment: username: @heynnema

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ruww.png]

Comment: @TajRasool please see my answer. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This repartition is actually pretty easy.

**Please note that it's normal to install Windows first, and Ubuntu second, and both should be installed in the same fashion... either BIOS mode or UEFI mode... with a new GPT partition table (which will wipe the disk) if your computer is in UEFI mode. It's best to make these decisions now, rather than trying to change it all later.**

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on /dev/sda2 in the lower pane and select **resize**
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda2 and reduce it by 400G
- right-click on the newly created unallocated space and create two new  200G partitions (EXT4 if it's for Ubuntu use, or NTFS to share with Windows, or NTFS if it's to become a Windows installation at a later date.)
- if everything looks correct, click the Apply icon