# Install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

I'm trying to install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 18.04 because I want to try some games on my laptop, and then go back to Ubuntu.

I have two USB Flash Drives, one with Windows 10 and the other with Ubuntu 18.04.

These are the steps I've done after following some answers here on Ask Ubuntu:

1. Booted on Live Ubuntu, and shrank my 1TB HDD into a 500 GB NTFS partition with GParted;
2. Booted on my Windows 10 USB Flash (on UEFI) and installing Windows without deleting the partition or formatting it, just by pressing next ( I also tried deleting it and make a new one with Windows, but I encounter the same issue);
3. After install, it was directly booting into windows, probably installing other stuff, and this is the annoying part, Windows froze at

   > Getting devices ready

   or something like this. I forced it to shut down and then .. continuing to step 4;
4. I booted again on my Live Ubuntu USB, and I have installed boot-repair, doing the recommended installation.
5. After installing boot-repair, I restarted my laptop, booted on Ubuntu OS redirecting me to GRUB Boot Loader, I selected Windows everything loaded then I got this error that Windows isn't installed properly and I have to restart and reinstall it.

I really don't know what to do any more, I deleted the NTFS partition and extended my ext4 partition, everything is normal now, but I really need Windows 10, I also need an answer on how to uninstall it and go back to normal.

This is one of the questions I was following, but it doesn't work for me: [Install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/699355)

And this is the second question, and I was following the first and the second answer, except doing the mount /boot thing because I didn't know what to do exactly: [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317)

EDIT : [Here's the summary of boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2CKCdSjGMG/)

Comment: Windows requires specific partitions for UEFI boot and drive must be gpt partitioned. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations  Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I added the summary report

Comment: Windows will not see the Linux ext4 partition and will complain. You either have to to backup & totally erase Linux partition with gparted, or create Windows partitions for UEFI boot. With BIOS, you only needed an NTFS partition, but it still liked more, but with UEFI you need the additional partitions. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Answer (score 0):

Remember the step you skipped While installing, it explicitly said don't turn off the system. If you want a clean slate you can boot from Hirens Boot, backup your data and unallocated every partition then merge them. Then start from step 1 again. If you want Windows, Then make sure your CPU architect is compatible with the one you choose in the start up. Second, it takes time so grab a coffee, And Then install Ubuntu on top of it. One more thing try to give windows an unallocated partition instead of a hand made NTFS one. If you all fails, get your HDD checked or get it wiped out clean. And if that failed..... you're in deep s**t.

Comment: I gave windows an unallocated partition. made from GParted that's what I'm saying, plus it didn't said anywhere to not turn off the system, it was only the loading animation and "Getting devices ready" plus I checked if my HDD had any activity from the LED

Comment: Not to argue but you don't turn off installations without seeing the desktop first in any case. If it's a different case where Windows doesn't install, then it's a different case. But you can clearly read it from the error message it hasn't installed fully. Give this one more shot from the top without hard shutting anything.

Comment: I might do the same thing again, by doing an unallocated partition, but I don't know what to do after I install Windows... Should I go straight to Ubuntu and install boot-repair and then boot in WIndows, or should I let windows do the job and leave this "Getting devices ready" and then do the boot-repair thing. It's night anyway so I can let it the whole night to get these devices ready though

Comment: okay read this carefully! 
1st : Make two unallocated partitions
2nd : Install Windows on one of them, wait for everything to settle down, as if wait until you see the desktop and you can click around.
3rd : Boot from Ubuntu and install it on the other unallocated partition. After then it will do all the repairing and grub configs for you automatically.
4th : reboot and check if both os are ready to go

Comment: it's loading at "Getting Ready"; I'll go to sleep and leave it like this and see what's happening, thanks

Comment: Update if you have succeeded

Comment: it's working very good, but can you also tell me how to uninstall it properly, and get rid of GRUB? Beacuse last time, I just deleted the partition, extended the Ubuntu one and GRUB was still there with the windows files

Comment: Uninstall Windows or Linux. If it's Windows, overwrite the main partiton, and that depends if you used EFI; then the booting partion is different from the main partion, it's a small partition so make sure to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not booting from the usb drive first. You need to check which one you have priority first when restarting. It checks if you're starting with windows or from the usb you have written the iso file on. check this site out(it's the one i used to see how to prioritize booting from my usb) https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10.

I also used this guys tutorial which really really helped me. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSVV_EoApdo&list=FL6PkExoBTT-JKR6oakVQC8Q&index=2&t=0s.

Good luck!